# Angular Website returns a blank page on IE11 (Invalid character error)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a website which was created with angualar and typescript.
Angular: 8.2.14 and TS: 3.5.3

It is working with all browsers expect IE(11). I only can see a blank page here. So I did several things, but nothing works.

the error is:

File:main.faf9a6cd66c650ae3ae6.js -> Invalid character at column 500971

I think this is some generated file and at column 500971 in the code there is a ` . I think this is the Problem? But i don't know how to solve this.

there are also some warnings that it was not able to load the script runtime-es5.js

**EDIT:**

----

If I use es2015, it seems to be working on IE, but not with Safari. And the other way around, if I try es5, it works with safari. But not with IE.
I may have to say that there is login site with a redirection after the login. Here you get a cookie, which is not forwarded I think. the Error is:

Failed to load resource: Cross-origin redirection

denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Origin

----

polyfills.ts

```
 import 'core-js'
 import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
 import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
 import './zone-flags.ts';
 import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

zone-flags.js:

```
(window as any).__Zone_disable_IE_check = true;
(window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>xyz</title>
  <script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.png">
</head>
<body>
<app-root stage="{{.Stage}}" username="{{.Username}}"></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

browserlist

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

angualar.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "xyz": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.png",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "xyz:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "xyz:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "xyz:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "xyz:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "xyz:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "xyz"
}
```

Comment: Was it generated with ng-cli? Can you share angular.json file?

Comment: Try adding this to the head of your index.html. `<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">`. I know we had something similar and needed the above because of corporate policies on IE11. It's a longshot if it'll work for you, but I'll give you it just incase it is the issue. It simply disables compatability view.

Comment: it was build with ng, yes. I added the angular.json

Comment: I don't use IE for testing Angular app. But I think `(window as any).__Zone_disable_IE_check = true;` should be `false`. Not sure but I believe this will enable check for IE and add some extra codes for IE in the build. Again, not sure because I don't use IE

Comment: sadly, adding the meta content or setting true to false did not work.

Comment: It's looks like that your code was not transpiled to es5, because ie11 doesn't support back ticks (`` symbol) but we can see it in the error. Maybe in tsconfig.app.json option "target" was set to "es2015"?

Comment: yes originally it was "es2015" but I changed it to es5. I have one problem now. If the target is "es2015" it works with IE but not with Safari ... and if i use "es5" it works with Safari but not with IE :-(

Comment: i added the problem to the question.

Comment: Make sure you have all the polyfills loaded, and not just the minimum recommended. Take a look in the node modules for more polyfills.